# How to render multiple textures/images (jpeg, pngs) using webgl2?

Tags: javascript, html, image, webgl, webgl2

I am working on a widget where I have to render 100s of rectangles and with that I have to render 100s of different images/textures (jpeg,png) on those rectangles. When I render an image/texture it overwrites the previous texture/image and only shows the latest rendered image which is 100th image for this example.

For reference, I am attaching code snippet

```
    // function to create image object and resolve
    const addImageProcess = (src) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => resolve(img);
      img.onerror = reject;
      img.src = src;
      img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    });
  };

  var texture;
  var promisesList = [];
  
  // Generates promise list
  for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    await promisesList.push(
      addImageProcess(url[i])
    );
  }

  // Iterate over the promise list and call the render function on image object
  promisesList.forEach((promise, index) => {
    promise
      .then((image) => {
        texture = dieImageUtils.createAndBindTexture(
          waferMapVariables.dieImageGl,
          image
        );
        render(texture, dieProgram, vertices[index], textureCoordinates[index]);
      })
      .catch(() => console.log("Crappy URL"));
  });




// Renderer function
 const render = (texture, program, vertices, textureCoordinates) => {
    var buffer = dieImageUtils.createAndBindBuffer(
      waferMapVariables.dieImageGl,
      waferMapVariables.dieImageGl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      waferMapVariables.dieImageGl.STATIC_DRAW,
      new Float32Array(vertices)
  );
  var texBuffer = dieImageUtils.createAndBindBuffer(
    waferMapVariables.dieImageGl,
    waferMapVariables.dieImageGl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    waferMapVariables.dieImageGl.STATIC_DRAW,
    new Float32Array(textureCoordinates)
  );
  waferMapVariables.dieImageGl.useProgram(program);

  // Step 4
  dieImageUtils.linkGPUAndCPU(
    {
      program: program,
      buffer: buffer,
      dims: 2,
      gpuVariable: "position",
    },
    waferMapVariables.dieImageGl
  );
  dieImageUtils.linkGPUAndCPU(
    {
      program: program,
      buffer: texBuffer,
      dims: 2,
      gpuVariable: "texCoords",
    },
    waferMapVariables.dieImageGl
  );
  waferMapVariables.dieImageGl.bindTexture(
    waferMapVariables.dieImageGl.TEXTURE_2D,
    texture
  );

  // Step 5
  waferMapVariables.dieImageGl.drawArrays(
    waferMapVariables.dieImageGl.TRIANGLES,
    0,
    vertices.length / 2
  );
};
```

Need a way to render images that it shows all 100 images/texture without overwriting any of previous rendered image/texture.

Comment: Assuming you are rendering each image one at a time you will need to create the webGL context with option `preserveDrawingBuffer` eg `canvas.getContext("webgl2", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true})`

Comment: It worked. ThankYou so much :-)

Comment: @Blindman67 Also this works if I have to render 100 different images for one time. But if I want to render another 100 images, the previous 100 images are still there on the canvas. Is there any way to deallocate the drawing buffer once first 100 images are rendered so when the next 100 images are rendered the previous images are gone?

Comment: To remove an image (texture) from the webGL context use `gl.deleteTexture(texture)`. If you just want to clear the canvas use `gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);` using the buffer bits of what you want to clear. For more on WebGL see reference card at https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf   a useful document